# How to implement a group function in mongoDB using JAVA

Tags: java, mongodb

The dataset can be found in http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/aggregation-zip-code-data-set/

Now , I am trying to implement the following function "Return Average City population by State":

```
db.zips.aggregate( { $group :
                     { _id : { state : "$state", city : "$city" },
                       pop : { $sum : "$pop" } } },
                   { $group :
                   { _id : "$_id.state",
                     avgCityPop : { $avg : "$pop" } } } )
```

with an output of: 
    {
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "RI",
            "avgCityPop" : 18933.28301886793
        }

Please help me in JAVA, Thank you

Comment: A simple google search for `mongodb java aggregation` shows you [`this link`](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-aggregation-framework-with-java-driver/) as the first result with an example

Comment: But it still a little bit different, how to write { _id : { state : "$state", city : "$city" } in JAVA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```java
// First $group operation
DBObject compoundId = new BasicDBObject( "state", "$state");
compoundId.append("city", "$city")
DBObject groupFields1 = new BasicDBObject( "_id", compoundId );
groupFields1.put("pop", new BasicDBObject( "$sum", "$pop"));
DBObject group1 = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields1);

// Second $group operation
DBObject groupFields2 = new BasicDBObject( "_id", "$_id.state");
groupFields2.put("avgCityPop", new BasicDBObject( "$avg", "$pop"));
DBObject group2 = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields2);

// Run aggregation
AggregationOutput output = collection.aggregate( group1, group2 );
```